# Baseboard Heater Quieting

Tags: heater, baseboard

I just purchased a home and am going through the process of correcting deficiencies and such. In two bedrooms, I have some rather loud baseboard heaters. I understand it's likely due to expanding and contracting, but is there something I can do to quiet the noises?  Thanks!

Comment: A description of the noise is needed. clanging, bang , click, continuous click etc. The term "rather loud" does not explain the problem.

Comment: It would also help to know if these are hot water (as in from a boiler somewhere else) type baseboard heaters, or electric baseboard heaters.

Comment: They are hot water baseboard heaters. Mostly its sporadic clanking. It seems like if a fin was jammed and then was set free after expanding, that is the sound I'm hearing.